# Letting a button blink white to red, then giving its old, rounded form

Tags: java, android, android-studio

I've already searched Stack Overflow but I just can't find the correct answer for my case.

I'm currently writing a quiz app in Android Studio and got stuck at blinking buttons whether the answer was correct or not.
If the answer is correct it should blink green and if the answer was incorrect it should blink red.

This is one of my answer buttons:

```
    <Button
    android:id="@+id/choice1"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="50dp"
    android:layout_marginBottom="24dp"
    android:fontFamily="@font/aldrich"
    android:padding="8dp"
    android:textColor="#fff"
    android:background="@drawable/rounded_button"/>
```

with this background:

```
    <solid android:color="#eeffffff" />
    <corners android:bottomRightRadius="12dp"
    android:bottomLeftRadius="12dp"
    android:topRightRadius="12dp"
    android:topLeftRadius="12dp"/>
```

To review the answer i use this onlickListener:

```
mButtonChoice1.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener()         
@Override
public void onClick(View view) {

            if (mButtonChoice1.getText() == mAnswer) {
                blinkEffectGreen1();

                Toast.makeText(QuizActivity.this,"Richtig!", 
Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
            else {
                blinkEffectRed1();
                Toast.makeText(QuizActivity.this, "Falsch,"  + " richtig 
wäre " + mAnswer + " gewesen", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
            mButtonChoice1.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.rounded_button);
            updateQuestion();
        }
    });
```

I try to use mButtonChoice1.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.rounded_button); to shape the button round again, because my blink method shapes it like a rectangle while blinking.

My blinkEffect Method looks like this:

```
private void blinkEffectRed1(){
    ObjectAnimator animator = ObjectAnimator.ofInt(mButtonChoice1, 
    "backgroundColor", Color.RED , Color.parseColor(("#ff669900")));
    animator.setDuration(250);
    animator.setEvaluator(new ArgbEvaluator());
    animator.setRepeatCount(2);
    animator.setRepeatMode(ValueAnimator.REVERSE);
    animator.start();
}
```

The problem is now, the app doesnt set the background as rounded_button again and the button stays a rectangle.

Why does this happen and how can I make the round button blink and get it round again?

If there is already a question like this answered I am sorry, please provide me the link then.

Thank you!

Comment: I guess you'd have to use an animation listener (`animator.addListener(...)`) and only when `onAnimationEnd` is called you need to call the `setBackgroundResource` method... Do you need an example code for that?

Comment: As I'm a noob in Android Studio could you give an example please?
Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When using animations, (sometimes) you want your UI related operations to be synchronous. To achieve that, you need to add an animation listener to the `ObjectAnimator` and call the `setBackgroundResource()` method when the animation ends.

Here is an example, I edited your `blinkEffectRed1` method:

```
private void blinkEffectRed1(){
  ObjectAnimator animator = ObjectAnimator.ofInt(mButtonChoice1, "backgroundColor", Color.RED , Color.parseColor(("#ff669900")));
  animator.setDuration(250);
  animator.setEvaluator(new ArgbEvaluator());
  animator.setRepeatCount(2);
  animator.setRepeatMode(ValueAnimator.REVERSE);

  // Adding the listener
  animator.addListener(new AnimatorListenerAdapter() {
    @Override
    public void onAnimationEnd(Animator animation) {
        // Update the button when animation ends...
        mButtonChoice1.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.rounded_button);
        updateQuestion();
    }
  });

  animator.start();
}
```

I hope that solves it :)

Answer (score 0):

You are animating backgroundColor of a view, it is going to animate background which is rectangle/square

Instead you have to implement alphaanimation

An example:

```
ObjectAnimator objAnimator = ObjectAnimator.ofFloat(mCircle, "alpha",0f,1f);
objAnimator.setDuration(1000);
objAnimator.setRepeatMode(Animation.REVERSE);
objAnimator.setRepeatCount(Animation.INFINITE);
objAnimator.start();
```

Answer (score 0):

Animate the button, once answer is true

```
if(answerTrue){

    // Set the color of the button to GREEN once.

    // Next, animate its visibility with the set color - which is GREEN as follows:

    Animation anim = new AlphaAnimation(0.0f, 1.0f);
    anim.setDuration(50); //You can manage the blinking time with this parameter
    anim.setStartOffset(20);
    anim.setRepeatMode(Animation.REVERSE);
    anim.setRepeatCount(Animation.INFINITE);
    button.startAnimation(anim);
}
```